# How to improve faction relations from a very negative value?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

After deciding to help [Arwa the Pearled One](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Arwa_the_Pearled_One), I found myself with some negative relations with several factions. I wasn't able to do much in those regions anymore, so I decided that I would start raiding their caravans to make money instead.

Now my faction relations are quite terrible. How do I go about setting these relations back to a more neutral position? Particularly, I want to get my relations with Sarranid Sultanate to a better value if possible.

Thanks! :)

[image: Picture depicting negative relations with factions.]

Comment: Zeus damn it, now I need to play Lemmings.

Comment: are you at a war state with those factions?  usually ratings reset when peace is made

Comment: Yeah, I am at a war state with them. They all declared war on me (eventually Khergit Khanate followed suit) after taking on Arwa the Pearled One and becoming the Sarrinade Rebels faction. Now I am at war with *everyone*. It sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find a faction lord while they are in the castle, you have the option of taking to them.  If your relationship with the lord is not too terrible, he will give you the option of paying a sum of money to fix your relationship with that kingdom.  This is usually a lot of money so it can be costly to fix relationships with all the kingdoms you have annoyed.

Comment: Trying this. Every time I follow a king around long enough for them to get into a castle, I try to go in to talk to them, and they just come out to attack me before I can approach. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Took some time to get a chance to approach them while the faction's King was in the castle, but I managed it. Worked. Set up a 40 day truce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the money or the desire to spend it to mend relations with a faction, you can slowly build your relationship up with them by releasing their lords after they are defeated in battle. Note that attacking a lord's army will slightly reduce your relations with that faction and lords may escape after a loss without giving you a chance to release them, so letting them come to you is preferred (of course, you would need to have a weaker army for this to happen reliably). While you're doing this, avoid attacking their villages and caravans, as this will only deepen the pit you're in.

Comment: Or you could just destroy them all for opossing your might :p

Comment: @Lyrion good point, that would certainly mitigate any downsides of having a negative relationship with them.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to just destroy each faction one by one. Take 'em on like a boss, and destroy them!

I'm gonna target other factions myself.

Comment: I found that hunting down the kings and paying them off was a *much* easier solution than wiping entire factions out. Wiping out an entire faction takes a long time in this game, especially depending on your difficulty setting. The more factions you destroy, the harder the others get as time passes and their own lands expand. Furthermore, this doesn't answer the question of how to **improve faction relations** - quite the opposite.